# Faster method to generate covariance matrix

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to make a covariance matrix from stocks returns in Excel.

I already have a sketchy method but would like to know if there is a faster way to do this.

So what I do is go to `Data -> Data Analysis -> Covariance` and set the parameters. And get something like this:

```
  A  B  C  D  E
1 1
2 N1 1
3 N2 N3 1 
4 N4 N5 N6 1
5 N7 N8 N9 N10 1
where N are the covariance between stocks
```

I would like my matrix to be like this:

```
  A  B  C  D  E
1 1  N1 N2 N4 N7
2 N1 1  N3 N5 N8
3 N2 N3 1  N6 N9
4 N4 N5 N6 1  N10
5 N7 N8 N9 N10 1
```

I tried to transpose the original matrix and put the original and transposed matrix together. This doesn't work because the blank spaces of the transposed matrix replace the original matrix's cell values. How to do this?

Answer (score 4):

1. Select your range
2. Press *F5 ..... Goto Special ... Blanks*
3. Enter this formula in the editing bar `=OFFSET($A$1,COLUMN()-1,ROW()-1)`
4. Press [ctrl](/questions/tagged/ctrl)[enter](/questions/tagged/enter) together to enter this into all the blank cells

[image]